# Статическая линковка библиотек QtApplication C++ на MSVS 2015

Tags: visual-c++, qt5

Необходимо статически собрать необходимые библиотеки Qt5.8 в проекте. Проект->Свойства проекта->С/С++->Создание кода->Библиотека времени исполнения меняю с MD на MT (Debug или Release, не важно). [image: Ошибки сборки]
Изменял параметр /NODEFAULTLIB в свойствах проекта->компоновщик, но там еще больше ошибок появлялось. Искал другие решения подобной проблемы, но везде предлагаю изменять Библиотеку времени выполнения на MT для статической линковки (что я и сделал сам). И эта проблема только для 1 файла (С остальными такой фигни не происходит).

Comment: qt по умолчанию собрано с поддержкой динамической линковки. Если Вам нужна статическая линковка - нужно покупать лицензию (насколько мне известно)

Comment: Я тоже об этом читал, но не уверен что нет другого выхода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняя флаг `/MD` на `/MT`, Вы меняете лишь компоновку *MSVC Runtime*, а не *Qt*. Чтобы компоновать статически *Qt*, её нужно пересобирать. Для этого при конфигурировании нужно будет указать ключ `-static`.

Но имейте в виду, что лицензия, под которой распространяется *Qt* (*LGPL*), в случае статической линковки требует выполнения одного из следующих условий:

- приложение должно распространяться под лицензией *GPL/LGPL*;
- должны предоставляться объектные коды приложения, чтобы приложение можно было перелинковать самостоятельно.

---

P.S. Кстати, если *Qt* собран с `/MD` (по умолчанию), а приложение с `/MT`, то возможны труднообнаружимые ошибки. *M$* не рекомендует этого делать.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.